# Do I need to low pass filter Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR?

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors, lowpass-filter

As stated in this [Readme](https://github.com/Bhide/Low-Pass-Filter-To-Android-Sensors/blob/master/README.md) it is recommended to low pass filter the Android sensors. Is this also recommended for the TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR sensor, which is a software sensor?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to do it. On some devices, low pass filter is not applied to software sensors:

```
public class LowPassFilter {
    // Time constant in seconds
    static final float timeConstant = 0.297f;
    private float alpha = 0.15f;
    private float dt = 0;
    private float timestamp = System.nanoTime();
    private float timestampOld = System.nanoTime();
    private float output[] = new float[]{ 0, 0, 0 };

    private long count = 0;

    public float[] lowPass(float[] input)
    {
        timestamp = System.nanoTime();

        // Find the sample period (between updates).
        // Convert from nanoseconds to seconds
        dt = 1 / (count / ((timestamp - timestampOld) / 1000000000.0f));

        count++;

        // Calculate alpha
        alpha = timeConstant / (timeConstant + dt);

        output[0] = calculate(input[0], output[0]);
        output[1] = calculate(input[1], output[1]);
        output[2] = calculate(input[2], output[2]);

        return output;
    }


    float calculate(float input, float output){
        float out = alpha * output  + (1 - alpha) * input;
        return out;
    }


}
```